# How to count the difference in Informix SQL?

Tags: sql, informix

I'm counting number of rated calls and average rating in callcenter:

```
select  cr.queue, ROUND(AVG(TO_NUMBER(cd.datavalue)),2) as average, count(*) as count
from callrecord cr
left join calldata cd on cd.callid=cr.callid 
where cd.datakey="qrate1" 
group by queue
```

```
|queue    |average   |count   |
+---------+----------+--------+
|sales    |3.92      |12      |
|service  |3.75      |4       |
```

(12 rated calls for sales and 4 rated calls for service).

I can also count number of total calls (rated and unrated):

```
select  cr.queue, 0 as average, count(*) as count
from callrecord cr
group by queue
```

```
|queue    |average   |count   |
+---------+----------+--------+
|sales    |0         |21      |
|service  |0         |4       |
```

(21 total calls for sales and 4 total calls for service).

But I want to count only unrated calls. SQL request:

```
select  cr.queue, 0 as average, count(*) as count
from callrecord cr
left join calldata cd on cd.callid=cr.callid 
where cd.datakey!="qrate1" 
group by queue
```

runs slowly and produce incorrect result, e.g.

```
|queue    |average   |count   |
+---------+----------+--------+
|sales    |0         |69      |
|service  |0         |16      |
```

(69 unrated calls for sales and 16 unrated calls for service - incorrect).

Hence count of unrated = total - rated, I can't build an SQL where I can get this result.

Desired result should be:

```
|queue    |average   |count   |
+---------+----------+--------+
|sales    |0         |9       |
|service  |0         |0       |
```

(21-12=9 unrated calls for sales and 4-4=0 unrated calls for service).

Example of CALLDATA table:

```
|callid   |datakey   |datavalue  |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|181      |ANI       |1234567890 |
|181      |DNIT      |2345678901 |
|181      |IVR_CHOICE|SALES      |
|182      |ANI       |1234567890 |
|182      |DNIT      |2345678901 |
|182      |QRATE1    |1          |
|183      |ANI       |1234567890 |
|183      |DNIT      |2345678901 |
|183      |LANG      |ENGLISH    |
```

Finally I have prepared a script for dbfiddle.uk to play with this scenario:

> ```
> select *
> into calldata
> from (values ('181','ANI','1234567890')
>      , ('181','DNIT','2345678901')
>      , ('181','IVR_CHOICE','SALES')
>      , ('182','ANI','1234567890')
>      , ('182','DNIT','2345678901')
>      , ('182','QRATE1','1')
>      , ('183','ANI','1234567890')
>      , ('183','DNIT','2345678901')
>      , ('183','LANG','ENGLISH') ) z(callid,datakey,datavalue);
>
> select *
> into callrecord
> from (values ('181','SALES')
>      , ('182','SALES' )
>      , ('183','SALES' ) ) z(callid,queue);     
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 12 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select queue, count(*) as total
> from callrecord
> group by queue
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> queue | total
> :---- | ----:
> SALES |     3
> ```

> ```
> select cr.queue, count(*) as rated
> from callrecord cr
> left join calldata cd on cr.callid=cd.callid
> where cd.datakey='QRATE1'
> group by queue
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> queue | rated
> :---- | ----:
> SALES |     1
> ```

> ```
> select cr.queue, count(*) as unrated
> from callrecord cr
> left join calldata cd on cr.callid=cd.callid
> where cd.datakey<>'QRATE1'
> group by queue
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> queue | unrated
> :---- | ------:
> SALES |       8
> ```

> ```
> select cr.queue, SUM(CASE WHEN cd.datakey='QRATE1' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as unrated
> from callrecord cr
> left join calldata cd on cr.callid=cd.callid
> group by queue
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> queue | unrated
> :---- | ------:
> SALES |       8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=97cddb13ebd480fcbc138e2b2a8adf60)*

Comment: When you post an SQL question, it helps no end to give an outline schema.  For example, you have a column `queue` — it is not absolutely clear which of the tables it belongs to, though the probability is that it's `callrecord` (only, not both).  It also isn't clear what is in the `calldetail` table, but it looks like it is probably an EAV ([Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)) model, which inherently makes querying difficult and typically slow.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have edited the original question and added an example of CALLDATA table. Your guess was true.

Comment: @Parfait, I have prepared a DBFIDDLE script with very simplified scenario that demonstrates an issue. Added at the bottom of initial question. So counting of total and rated is OK. Counting of unrated (last two request) provides 8 instead of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not want to count the child table, *calldata*, matched records but only *callrecord* level records, consider using `EXISTS` clause (or `IN`) with correlated subquery:

```
-- EXISTS
select cr.queue, count(*) as rated
from callrecord cr
where exists (
  select 1 from calldata cd
  where cd.callid = cr.callid
  and cd.datakey = 'QRATE1'
)
group by queue


-- NOT EXISTS
select cr.queue, count(*) as rated
from callrecord cr
where not exists (
  select 1 from calldata cd
  where cd.callid = cr.callid
  and cd.datakey = 'QRATE1'
)
group by queue
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a1e62571cab973eca95b8844d46634de)</kbd>

Comment: This construction works fine for DBFIDDLE example  [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=65047f45720bd0261856652dbcf4f754).

Now I'm trying to apply it to my real DB. It runs slow, provide result close to real, but not exact. I need some time to investigate what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try indexing `callid` in both tables and `datakey`. Note: my demo link shows two approaches with `EXISTS` and `IN` which can differ in performance.

Comment: I have discovered the problem: CALLRECORD may have several records with the same CALLID (when call is transferred between queues). 
Logically, rating (if exist) should refer to the last step of a call.
So I would expect that one CALLID should be counted only once.
I tried to improve the result by using COUNT(DISTINCT CALLID) instead of COUNT(*), but it still differs from the desired one.

Comment: I have modified an example with this conditions.
[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb03785511c0cafa0a433e067f1728da)
Total and unrated should be 1 for SERVICE.
@Parfait, In principle this is a different task. Your example provides accurate solution for my initial question, so it is answered.

Comment: What do you expect for `callid` 181 ? It is not rated, but it was on queue `SALES` and `SERVICE`. Where should it appear as unrated? As `SALES` or as `SERVICE`? There is seems to be no way to determine which was the last step of the call.

Comment: @Luís Marques, I have mentioned above, that _logically, rating (if exist) should refer to the last step of a call. So I would expect that one CALLID should be counted only once._